# Adjust UIButton label font ,to screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have buttons that created in code, and their size is in % from the screen size, so
they change their width and height proportionally to the screen .

The only thing that remains in the same size is the font size .

I know there is a way to set minimum font size with :

```
  CAT.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Gill Sans" size:12];
CAT.titleLabel.numberOfLines=1;
CAT.titleLabel.minimumFontSize=2; //not good
```

But, the last row here ,minimum size ,is deprecated ,and so Xcode will not allowed to use it.

So , i was also try to set it to fit to width with :

```
CAT.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
```

Which results in *different* font sizes for buttons with the same width and height , so i can see 10 buttons in the **same frame**,and **different text length** but with completely different font size .I guess its width is the same as the text width and not the button frame.width .

Is there other solution to fit the frame ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `CAT.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor` to set the minimum font size. It takes in a multiplier value against the current font size.